# Prove that every triangle-free graph is $\lceil 2\sqrt{n}\rceil$ colorable

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Prove that every triangle-free graph is  $\lceil 2\sqrt{n}\rceil$ colorable

Comment: I really don't have a clue even how to approach this question... I 'll be happy for a clue
I thought about induction , but still...

Comment: I do know that from mantel the number of edges is at most $n^2/4$.
I am not sure what you mean by density...

Comment: @zarathustra can you give me a more concrete proof?

Comment: @zarathustra: Excellent! The question should be reopened and then closed as a duplicate.